# C++ Throw exception in constructor

Tags: c++, exception, constructor

```
class MyClass {
    
    std::string filename;

public:
    MyClass(std::string new_filename);
    ~MyClass();
}
```

MyClass.hpp

```
#include <MyClass.hpp>

MyClass::MyClass(std::string new_filename) {

   filename = new_filename;
}

MyClass::~MyClass() {};
```

MyClass.cpp

I want the constructor only to run when the filename is of a correct form. E.g.: "Name.aa.js".

I tried it with exception handling but I don't quite understand how to use it correctly.
I have a function that checks whether the given string parameter is of the correct form.

```
static bool MyClass::is_filename(std::string name) {

   if (regex_match(name, std::regex("(Name.)[a-z]{2}(.js)"))) {
       
       return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

And then I put

```
if (!is_filename(new_filename)) {

   throw;
}
```

at the beginning of my constructor. When I run my Code with a wrong filename it just outputs "Debug Error", but works with a correct filename. I also tried

```
throw std::invalid_argument;
```

But it says

> base of all invalid-argument exceptions

> no instance of constructor 'std::invalid_argument::invalid_argument' matches the argument list

Where and how exactly do I have to use the throw argument? Do I need to implement try / catch aswell for this to work?

Comment: well, what do you expect from an uncaught exception? if you don't want your program to terminate you have to catch it, as you said

Comment: The solitary `throw` can only be used in an exception handler, and it rethrows the exception that the handler is handling.

Comment: On a side note, `if (condition) return true; return false;` --> `return condition;`

Answer (score 3):

[`std::invalid_argument`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/invalid_argument) has no default constructor (one that can be called without parameters). There are two constructors taking a message (either as `const char*` or `std::string`):

```
throw std::invalid_argument("wrong filename");
```

> Where and how exactly do I have to use the throw argument?

When an object cannot be constructed then the constructor is the right place to throw an exception.

> Do I need to implement try / catch aswell for this to work?

Depends. You need no `try`/`catch` to throw an exception, but if the exception is not caught then your program will terminate.

Answer (score 3):

`throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid argument.");` would work. The constructor requires an argument to be passed.

You'll need to catch the exception though somewhere further up the call stack. Do that with

```
try {
    // your function here
} catch (const std::exception& e){
    // deal with the exception here, use e.what() to extract the message
}
```

Alternatively, you can catch `std::invalid_argument` or `std::logic_error` depending on how generic you want to be.

Note that `throw;` on its own can be used at a catch site to throw the current exception *by reference*. It is the only *nullary* operator in C++.

Comment: "It is the only nullary operator in C++" is one of my C++ trivia questions!

Comment: So should I put: filename = new_filename; inside a try{} block, followed by a catch block? When I tried that, the program still aborts and outputs an error message: 'Debug Error'.